# Toggle li don't work after json load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

i tried to build an color system management but i'm newbies and it's so difficult for me !

My problem is :

when i load my html page, all work fine, but when i click on the "li" element for load json, all my toggle elements don't work !!! strange , where is the problem please ? syntax?

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="theme-item">
        <ul class="color-list one">
            <li>
                <span class="in"></span>
            </li>
</ul>
</div>


<ul class="elements-list">
    <li class="elements-item">
        <span class="tog">test one</span>
        <div class="togcont hidden">
            <h5 data-title="">text text</h5>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQUERY CODE :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ----------------------
    // JSON INFOS
    // ----------------------   
  $(".color-list li").click(function(event){
    $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
      $('ul.elements-list').html('<li class="elements-item"><span class="tog">' + jd.name + '</span><div class="togcont"><p>Name: ' + jd.name + '</p></div></li>');
      $('ul.elements-list').append('<li class="elements-item"><span class="tog">' + jd.age + '</span><div class="togcont hidden">Name: ' + jd.age + '</div></li>');
      $('ul.elements-list').append('<li class="elements-item"><span class="tog">' + jd.sex + '</span><div class="togcont hidden">Name: ' + jd.sex + '</div></li>');

    });
  });

    // ----------------------
    // TOGGLE BULLZ
    // ----------------------
    $(".tog").click(function(){
        var obj = $(this).next();
            if($(obj).hasClass("hidden")){
                $(obj).removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
                $(this).addClass("bounce");
            } else {
                $(obj).addClass("hidden").slideUp();
                $(this).removeClass("bounce");
        }
    });


});
```

CSS CODE (PART) :

```
ul.elements-list {
    list-style-position: inside;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

ul.elements-list li {
    margin: 20px 0;
    background-color:  #393939;
    border-radius: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;   
}

ul.elements-list li .tog {
    color: #FFF;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor:pointer;
}

div.togcont {
    padding:15px 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    display: none;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color: #CCC;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', ".tog", function(){
```

Since the click handler is attached before you append the new elements, you need to delegate this click handler for the event to be caught.

Check the documentation for [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). - Which means "$(document).on(" is a safe card

Answer (score 1):

Try [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", ".tog", function(){
```

You need [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)